# PHP RegEx: How to extract certain words from a sentence?

Tags: php, regex

I have a Wikitext like:

> Directed by David Fincher. Written by Jim Uhls. Based on the novel by
>   Chuck Palahniuk.

I am trying to make regex that only fetches *David Fincher* and *Jim Uhls*, both name will vary based on url. I made following Regex and it does work (after replacing unwanted text), is there some better way?

```
/(Directed by)([\w\s]+). (Written by)([\w\s]+). /g
```

Comment: Check [`(?:Written|Directed)\s+by\s+([\w\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/O5Uk9D/1). You may use it with `preg_match_all` to get multiple values.

Comment: Sidequestion: At which point is it more efficient to use a new preg call instead of a long line of `|` connected words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:Directed|Written)\s*by\s` this will match `Directed by` or `Written by`

`\K` will discard previous matches.

`[^\.]+` this will match upto character `.` dot(excluding .dot).

**Regex:** `/(?:Directed|Written)\s*by\s+\K[^.]+/g`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/5PRF2t/5)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='Directed by David Fincher. Written by Jim Uhls. Based on the novel by Chuck Palahniuk.';
preg_match_all("/(?:Directed|Written)\s*by\s+\K[^.]+/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => David Fincher
            [1] => Jim Uhls
        )

)
```

Comment: If you use `\K`, there is no need using a capturing group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\K` here is helping me to match only names.

Comment: No, `\K` discards all the text matched so far. Capturing is done with a pair of unescaped parentheses. You do not need them here.

Comment: as OP want only `David Fincher` and `Jim Uhls` thats why i have used it,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But okay if you are saying that it is not correct then may be it is not. Changing it.

Comment: The beauty of `\K` is that you can simplify the match array structure by removing what you do not need before the actual match. When you add capturing parentheses after `\K`, you double the values in the array. That is why I say you do not need them here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is this regex is okay `(?:Directed|Written)\s*by\s\K(?:[^\.]+)` ? I got your point

Comment: They all work, just there is no need to enclose a pattern sequence with a non-capturing group if it contains no alternation, nor quantified: `(?:Directed|Written)\s*by\s+\K[^.]+`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest I can think of:

```
<?php

// https://regex101.com/r/dxft9p/1

$string = 'Directed by David Fincher. Written by Jim Uhls. Based on the novel by Chuck Palahniuk.';
$regex = '#Directed by (?<director>\w+\s?\w+). Written by (?<author>\w+\s?\w+)#';
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

echo 'Director - '.$matches['director']."\n";
echo 'Author - '.$matches['author'];
```

See here for a working example https://3v4l.org/AuDL0

When you use `(?<somelabel> blah)` in brackets, you create a named capture group. Very handy!